# Trying to get property 'price' of non-object in laravel

Tags: database, laravel

There's so many question about this but because I'm a newbie, I don't get it at all. so I've successfully saving multiple data into my db. I have 2 tables, TicketPrice as a list of price that visitor would choose, then I will save the selected data into Payment table. This is what I've done in my controller:

```
    $idcategory = $request->id_category;
    $price = $request->price;
    $qty = $request->qty;
    $data = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($idcategory as $key => $value) {
      if ($qty[$i] > 0) {
        for ($k=0; $k < $qty[$i] ; $k++) {
          $data[] = [
              "id_category" => $value,
              "name" => $request->nama[$key],
              "price" => $request->price[$key],
              "qty" => $request->qty[$key],
          ];
        }

      }

      $i++;
    }
    Payment::insert($data);
    $latest = News::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->take(3)->get();
    return view('form.conference-regist',compact('latest'))->with('data',$data);
```

and this is when I try to foreach the selected data (it's multiselect) in my blade after saving it on Payment table:

```
     <?php foreach ($data as $key): ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Price</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="price" value="{{$key->price}}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I wonder if it necessary to put hasMany or belongsTo into the models? Or is there any easier way to solved it?

Comment: when `dd($data)` what it gives after successful insertion ?

Comment: it gives an array of $data

Comment: check answer, i think you want all data back to be accessable in your view, right ?

Answer (score 0):

**Well you can try this to get the inserted data back and to pass it to view**

```
$data2 = Payment::insert($data);
$data2 = $data2->fresh(); //this will re-retrieve the inserted data back from table.
$latest = News::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->take(3)->get();
return view('form.conference-regist',compact('latest'))->with('data',$data2);
```